# Liquid array for loop conditional?

Tags: liquid

I have an array of posts each with a category. I want to display 3 posts from a subset of those categories (we'll say a,b,c). Is there any way of doing this with core liquid? Unless I'm just not thinking of something I don't think there is.

Example array of posts:

```
[
 {title: post 1, category: {id: a}},
 {title: post 2, category: {id: b}},
 {title: post 3, category: {id: c}},
 {title: post 4, category: {id: d}},
 {title: post 5, category: {id: b}}
]
```

I'd need something like this pseudo code:

```
{% for post in posts where category.id == a|b|c limit: 3 %}
```

or

```
{% for post in posts %}
  {% if post.category.id == a|b|c limit: 3 %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way:

```
{% assign counter = 0 %}
{% for post in posts %}
  {% if counter < max and categories contains post.category.id %}
    {% assign counter = counter | plus:1 %}
    counter={{counter}}, post= {{post.title}} 
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Running the following Ruby script:

```ruby
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'liquid.rb'

template = <<BLOCK
{% assign counter = 0 %}
{% for post in posts %}
  {% if counter < max and categories contains post.category.id %}
    {% assign counter = counter | plus:1 %}
    counter={{counter}}, post= {{post.title}} 
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
BLOCK

posts = [
  { "title" => "post 1", "category" => { "id" => "a" } },
  { "title" => "post 2", "category" => { "id" => "e" } },
  { "title" => "post 3", "category" => { "id" => "c" } },
  { "title" => "post 4", "category" => { "id" => "d" } },
  { "title" => "post 5", "category" => { "id" => "f" } },
  { "title" => "post 6", "category" => { "id" => "b" } },
  { "title" => "post 7", "category" => { "id" => "e" } },
  { "title" => "post 8", "category" => { "id" => "b" } }
]

print Liquid::Template.parse(template).render({
    'posts' => posts, 
    'max' => 3,
    'categories' => ['a', 'b', 'c']
})
```

produces the following output:

```
counter=1, post= post 1    
counter=2, post= post 3 
counter=3, post= post 6
```

*(stripped some of the line breaks though)*

Answer (score 1):

You can use *Where Expression*

```
{% assign posts = site.post 
| where_exp:"p", "p.category.id = 'a' or p.category.id = 'b' or p.category.id = 'c'" 
| limit: 3 %}

{% for post in posts %}
--> your code
```